# parse json with swift 3 not working for me

Tags: json, swift3

I'm trying to get the "name" from the following json file for a couple of days now, without success. Can anyone please guide me in the right direction? I've managed to access the results array but not the "name" variable.

```
{
    "count": 7,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
    {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Abs"
    },
    {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Arms"
    },
    {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Back"
    },
    {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Calves"
    },
    {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Chest"
    },
    {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Legs"
    },
    {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Shoulders"
    }
    ]
}
```

and my code looks like this

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercisecategory")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let content = data {

                do {
                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options:[]) {
                        if let content = json as? [String: Any] {
                            if let results = content["results"] as? [Any] {
                                for result in results {
                                    if let bodypart = result["name"] as! [String: Any] {
                                        print(bodypart)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are casting `name` to `Dictionary` but it is simply `String` also you need to cast `results` array to Array of dictionary instead of Array of `Any`. So whole code would be like.

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options:[]), 
   let content = json as? [String: Any], 
   let results = content["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {
      for result in results {
          if let bodypart = result["name"] as? String {
              print(bodypart)
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: @Niklas Welcome mate :)